# How to extract MFCC features in PocketSphinx

Tags: java, android, sphinx4, mfcc, pocketsphinx-android

I am using the PocketSphinx Demo project for my hot word detection Android app and now I'd like to extract the MFCC features. Is it possible to do so with PocketSphinx?

Also, I've read many posts about using Sphinx 4 for Android, some say it can be done, some say it can't. I personaly didn't manage to make it work.
Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> now I'd like to extract the MFCC features. Is it possible to do so with PocketSphinx?

No, this feature is not supported

> Also, I've read many posts about using Sphinx 4 for Android, some say it can be done, some say it can't. I personaly didn't manage to make it work. Thank you for your help,

Sphinx4 on Android is not supported either